# Android Studio failed to open by giving error "Files Locked"

Tags: android-studio

After running once successfully, Android Studio is getting failed to open.
The error is:

> Files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\system\caches are locked. Android Studio will not be able to start.

Did any one find its solution?

Comment: Verify in WTM that the previous studio process is not running. If it is - kill it

Comment: Did you try to shut down the process in Task Manager?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Solved in Windows 7:

1. Go to folder where android-studio is installed. (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio`)
2. Now go up one folder. (i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android`)
3. Right click on the `android-studio` folder and go to **Properties**.
4. In the **Properties** window, go to the **Security** tab.
5. Click the **Edit** button.
6. A new window will open, here you click the **Users** (your-username-or-your-group-name)
7. From the list below, check **Allow** in front of **Full control**.
8. Press **OK**, then again **OK**.

Now you can use Android Studio easily instead of "Running it As Administrator" every time.

Comment: You could also add authenticated user and give full control in case of Windows 8 using your hotmail account as login.

Comment: When installing, If I had installed only for user and not for all, then this problem may have not come!

Comment: Worked for Windows 10 too. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

If you are running in Windows 7 / Vista/ etc. then try running Android Studio as administrator. I was having the same problem and this fixed it for me.

Comment: This works. Note that the executable is located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin

Comment: You can mark the Android Studio shortcut to always run as administrator by right clicking the shortcut and selecting properties -> (shortcut tab) Advanced... -> check the "Run As Administrator" checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

I installed it for all users too, and got this same error on second run. Didn't want to reinstall it, and also prefer not to run programs as admin unless necessary, so I just changed a couple file permissions and it runs fine.

I changed the settings on C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio and let it apply to all sub-folders -- removed Read-Only, and gave localhost/Users group permissions to modify files in this folder.  Worked fine afterwards.  If you want to be more secure, just give your user permissions to modify those folders.

Comment: I found that changing the permissions (Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Permissions -> Change Permissions) on the folder to give the Users group full control of the %ProgramFiles%\Android\android-studio folder solved the issue.

Comment: Be careful with full control-- it allows other users to change the file permissions, including possibly removing your ability to modify the file. Modify is usually the safer bet.

Answer (score 2):

During the installation, select "install for the current user". Android Studio will be installed in the user's folders, without any authorization issues. Personally I do not like to run program with Administrator power.

Comment: Installing for all users puts the studio in "Program Files" which seems to inherit a read only flag for all subfolders and files (for me on Win 7). But the caches folder in the studio is something that apparently needs to be mutable. why notput the caches someplace else shared but not read only?

Comment: @Greg: Yes... Putting the caches folder in %ProgramData% or even each user's %AppData% directory would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

if u install for all users than , run as admin will solve it .
Tested in windows 8 also.

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLEST SOLUTION:
Uninstall Android Studio and install it again 
I had the same problem and it solved .

Answer (score 0):

Simply go and delete the cache folder from user .AndroidStudio3. . It solved problem