# Android studio isn't starting

Tags: android-studio

I have installed an Android studio from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download). It worked, i wrote a hello world project and then closed it. But the IDE does not start second time. It gives me an error "caches are locked".

[image]

I installed [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and it says that no process blocks this folder. Does anybody know where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856650/android-studio-failed-to-open-by-giving-error-files-locked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced this problem. I have solve my problem as follows:

1. Go to folder where android-studio is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio)
2. Now go back to previous folder. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android)
3. Right click on the android-studio folder and go to properties.
4. Now in Properties window, go to Security Tab.
5. Click the Edit Button
6. Now, a new window will open, here you click the Users(your-username-or-your-group-name)
7. Now, from the List below, Check "Allow" in front of "Full control"
8. Now press "OK", then again "OK"..
9. Its done.. Now you can use Android Studio easily instead of Running it As Administrator every time..

For details please visit [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=56230&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=56230) page

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me, you could be trying to start a version prior to 0.2.0  (in my case 0.1.6)

Following Google's notes here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

You'll need to remove and re-install Android Studio 0.2.0 & up

"Note: There is not a patch update available from 0.1.9 to 0.2. To update from Android Studio 0.1.x to 0.2.x, you must install a new Android Studio bundle from this page. The reason for that is that we have made changes to the bundled SDK such that it includes a pre-configured local Maven repository which can serve up the v4 support library and which is required for creating new projects."

Also be aware that if you have your Android SDK files stored here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk

You should move them before the uninstall or you'll need to download the SDK files again.

After the un-install and re-install now working on my Windows 7 64-bit system