# Android studio is not starting (cannot lock the system folder)

Tags: android

[image]

android studio is not starting after installation and giving this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio failed to open by giving error "Files Locked"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856650/android-studio-failed-to-open-by-giving-error-files-locked)

Comment: For Mac users try by reseting all your network preferences [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966176/android-studio-fails-to-start-with-error-cannot-lock-system-folders-on-macos/50421531#50421531)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this ,

1) open cmd with Run as administrator

2) type: netsh winsock reset

3) restart computer

After restart open Android Studio and check for errors if no errors all fine!

else try the following:

1. Set the environment variables for JAVA_HOME
2. Disabled UAC ( User access Controls in windows)
3. Updated to the latest Java Version
4. Reinstalled Android Studio
5. Update windows if you are on it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to folder where android-studio is installed. (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio`)
2. Now go up one folder. (i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android`)
3. Right click on the `android-studio` folder and go to **Properties**.
4. In the **Properties** window, go to the **Security** tab.
5. Click the **Edit** button.
6. A new window will open, here you click the **Users** (your-username-or-your-group-name)
7. From the list below, check **Allow** in front of **Full control**.
8. Press **OK**, then again **OK**.

Now you can use Android Studio easily instead of "Running it As Administrator" every time.

Original Answer :[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856650/android-studio-failed-to-open-by-giving-error-files-locked)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile in windows, like c:\Users\kandpal\ and look for folders named .android and .android2.x (which will be the latest version of android installed) and make sure it is not read only type by going through its properties. If it is made read only, uncheck it on the .android folders, which will surely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its just an issue of firewall.....
1)Firewall must be turned on.
2)Allow the application through windows firewall settings....if the application is not present by default, add it and grant permissions....Hope it will solve your issue.