# Android Studio fails to start with error "Cannot Lock System Folders" on macOS

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

So what happens is that every time I open Android Studio, this happens:

[image]

I used Android Studio successfully before.

I've searched everywhere for the solution to the problem, but ***all the answers I got are only relevant to Windows*** and not for macOS.

I've tried reinstalling Android Studio but that does not seem to help. Does not seem to be an antivirus issue either cause disabling has no difference. Tried looking for permissions issue but I can't find the equivalent one in macOS.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Check the folder permissions where Android Studio is installed or the project Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it work to reset all network configuration on Mac. My system is High Sierra. On terminal type `cd /Library/Preferences` and then type `sudo rm -r SystemConfiguration`.

All the SystemConfiguration files will go away but one (just type n or y). Restart. All the files will be regenerated on restart.

All your network configuration will go away, but is better to setup that again than a not working Android Studio

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the only solution that actually worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked on Windows by going to *C:\Users\"Your username"* and finding the *.android* and *.AndroidStudio* folders. Open properties of both the folders and uncheck the **hidden** and **Read-only** properties.
Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This question has however been answered for Windows many times such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856650/android-studio-failed-to-open-by-giving-error-files-locked) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360397/android-studio-is-not-starting-cannot-lock-the-system-folder). While your contribution is definitely welcome, the asker was specifically asking for a solution on macOS